# Schottky diodes as full bridge rectifier

Tags: diodes, rectifier, schottky, full-bridge

I need to make a 75-100VDC high current power supply. I do not have any high current diodes or bridge rectifier ICs but I do have a load of scrap switching power supplies.

Could I take 4 of the (lack of better terms) Schottky diode modules that have 2 diodes pointing into each other, such as [this one](https://www.onsemi.jp/PowerSolutions/document/MBR20100CT-D.PDF), and arrange them in the full bridge rectifier layout? That datasheet is not the one I will use, I just added it as an example. However will the high reverse leakage current of Schottky diodes present a problem here?

Here is how I would use them. Note the blue resistor is the load. Also the power supply I am building is high current. One of the diode modules is pictured at top left. And the diodes in the picture are obviously meant to be Schottky diodes. Could I get more current by paralleling both diodes?

[image]

The diodes I have that I think might work are a bunch of [byv72e](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/65796.pdf).
I also got a bunch of [DSEI 3006A](http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DSEI30-06A.pdf)

Comment: How do you propose to arrange two of those common-cathode dual diode modules into a full wave rectifier topology? I think you'll have to use at least three.

Comment: Updated post. Added schematic

Comment: the FREDs dissipate 50Wpk at 37Apk but if you have 10% V ripple then duty cycle is only 10% . Mount all pairs using mica with grease to a good heat sink and then you can share current in parallel at same temp and same voltage Vf which drops with rising temp. those are the best bet for Line Voltage PLT’s (power line transients) with 600V rating

Comment: @electonicsnoob: read your question title again.

Comment: I know I just wanted to know the drawbacks tbh

Comment: Due to the high reverse leakage, Schottky devices are prone to thermal runaway.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, but you want to design the thing so that the highest reverse voltage on the diode is about 80% of the rated value.  You may have some trouble finding Schottkeys that'll do that for a 100V supply.

Comment: I have some rated up to 200v. Would those work?

Comment: We need a schematic -- please edit your question.

Comment: Updated post. Added schematic